# How to pass Vec<Value>> in rusqlite as query param

Tags: rust, rusqlite

I'm following the example from the rusqlite git hub https://github.com/rusqlite/rusqlite/blob/master/src/vtab/array.rs#L206. I have the exact same code but I get the compile error

```
the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<rusqlite::types::Value>: rusqlite::ToSql` is not satisfied
```

A snippet of the code is below. ids is a Vec of String

```
let intValues:Vec<i64> = ids.into_iter().map(|s| s.parse::<i64>().expect("Id Parse error.")).collect();
let values:Vec<rusqlite::types::Value> = intValues.into_iter().map(rusqlite::types::Value::from).collect();
let ptr = std::rc::Rc::new(values);
let mut statement = db_connection
    .prepare("select * from item where id in rarray(?);")
    .expect("Failed to prepare second query.");
let results = statement

// This is the error line
    .query_map(&[&ptr], |row| {
        Ok(database::ItemData {
            id: row.get(0)?,
            name: row.get(1)?,
            time_to_prepare: row.get(2)?
        })
    });
```

Comment: you don't show the real code https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.25.3/rusqlite/vtab/array/type.Array.html => `let ptr = std::rc::Rc::new(values);` => `the trait bound std::vec::Vec<rusqlite::types::Value>: rusqlite::ToSql`. Not possible. Check version, checke everything twice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. This is my real code and this is the error I'm getting. I checked the version before posting here.

Comment: What is the difference between carray and rarray? I just found doc for "carray": https://sqlite.org/carray.html linked in the Rusqlite documentation of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add "array" to the feature in the toml file.

Comment: How? Could you give more details?

Comment: Like this 
rusqlite = { version = "0.25.3", features = ["bundled", "array"] }